# Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type IXXXXXController, key ""

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mef

We are getting below error when try to get the object by using ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance() method.

**Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type IXXXXXController, key ""**

at Microsoft.Internal.Collections.WeakReferenceCollection`1.<CleanupDeadReferences>b__0(WeakReference w)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.RemoveAll(Predicate`1 match)
   at Microsoft.Internal.Collections.WeakReferenceCollection`1.CleanupDeadReferences()
   at Microsoft.Internal.Collections.WeakReferenceCollection`1.Add(T item)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.StartSatisfyingImports(PartManager partManager, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImports(PartManager partManager, ComposablePart part, Boolean shouldTrackImports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.SatisfyImports(ComposablePart part)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionServices.GetExportedValueFromComposedPart(ImportEngine engine, ComposablePart part,

ExportDefinition definition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportedValue(CatalogPart part, ExportDefinition export, Boolean isSharedPart)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.CatalogExport.GetExportedValueCore()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.get_Value()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ImportingItem.Cast(Type type, Export export)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ImportingItem.CastSingleExportToImportType(Type type, Export export)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ImportingItem.CastExportsToSingleImportType(Export[] exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ImportingItem.CastExportsToImportType(Export[] exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ReflectionComposablePart.SetImport(ImportingItem item, Export[] exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ReflectionComposablePart.SetImport(ImportDefinition definition, IEnumerable`1 exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.PartManager.TrySetImport(ImportDefinition import, Export[] exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImportSubset(PartManager partManager, IEnumerable`1 imports, AtomicComposition

atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImportsStateMachine(PartManager partManager, ComposablePart part)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImports(PartManager partManager, ComposablePart part, Boolean shouldTrackImports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.SatisfyImports(ComposablePart part)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionServices.GetExportedValueFromComposedPart(ImportEngine engine, ComposablePart part,

ExportDefinition definition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportedValue(CatalogPart part, ExportDefinition export, Boolean isSharedPart)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.CatalogExport.GetExportedValueCore()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.get_Value()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.GetCastedExportedValue[T](Export export)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.<>c__DisplayClass10`2.<CreateSemiStronglyTypedLazy>b__c()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.MefServiceLocatorAdapter.DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\release\WorkingDir

\PrismLibraryBuild\PrismLibrary\Desktop\Prism.MefExtensions\MefServiceLocatorAdapter.cs:line 73
   at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)

---

We are setting up the container in class (inside *override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog* method) derived from MefBootstrapper like below

**this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(ClassName).Assembly));**

We have observed that this work fine for some time but we start getting the error when we leave the application ideal for few hours. Please suggest what is causing this error and fix for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use MEF with Prism.  MEF support is being dropped in a future release.  Please use a real container.

Comment: Thank for your response but considering the fact that its already being used, do you see any solution to this.

Comment: I have no idea as I don't use MEF.